# bootstrap pull-left and pull-right class not working in angular

Tags: css, angular, twitter-bootstrap

so basically im doing this in angular and using bootstrap

I want the name and description on the left and img on the right but it isn't working , pls help
code  link is below

[here](https://codepen.io/wlommusic/pen/mdWddBP)

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <button class='btn btn-success'>New bug</button>
    </div>  
</div>
<hr>
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-xs-12">
 <a href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix" 
    style="background:grey ; color:red;" 
    *ngFor="let bug of bugs">
            <div class="pull-left">
                <h4 class="list-group-item-headin">name</h4>
                <p class="list-group-item-text">description</p>
                <span class="list-group-item-text">type</span>
                <span class="list-group-item-text">status</span>
                <span class="list-group-item-text">priority</span>                  </div>  
          <div class="pull-right">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/Dead-Bug_43215-480x360_%285000576310%29.jpg" 
       alt="{{bug.name}}" 
       class="img-responsive" 
       style="max-height: 100px;">
 </div>
            </a> 
        <app-bugs-item></app-bugs-item>
    </div>  
</div>
```

Comment: You can use the class `justify-content-between` and `d-flex` on the parent element to accomplish what you want.

Comment: I think they changed the class names from `pull-left` to `float-left`. If I use these classes instead your example is working

Comment: from bootstrap.4.0 has been removed:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/migration/#utilities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you want the text to wrap around the image. If that is the case then only put the float class on the image, and reorder the image to above the text.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <button class="btn btn-success">New bug</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item clearfix" style="background: grey; color: red" *ngFor="let bug of bugs">
        <div class="float-right">
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/Dead-Bug_43215-480x360_%285000576310%29.jpg" alt="{{bug.name}}" class="img-responsive" style="max-height: 100px" />
        </div>
        <h4 class="list-group-item-headin">name</h4>
        <p class="list-group-item-text">description</p>
        <span class="list-group-item-text">type</span>
        <span class="list-group-item-text">status</span>
        <span class="list-group-item-text">priority</span>
      </a>
      <app-bugs-item></app-bugs-item>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you want the text and image to be in 2 columns I would suggest using flexbox

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <button class="btn btn-success">New bug</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <hr />
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      <a href="#" class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between" style="background: grey; color: red" *ngFor="let bug of bugs">
        <div>
          <h4 class="list-group-item-headin">name</h4>
          <p class="list-group-item-text">description</p>
          <span class="list-group-item-text">type</span>
          <span class="list-group-item-text">status</span>
          <span class="list-group-item-text">priority</span>
        </div>
        <div>
          <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/3/3f/Dead-Bug_43215-480x360_%285000576310%29.jpg" alt="{{bug.name}}" class="img-responsive" style="max-height: 100px" />
        </div>
      </a>
      <app-bugs-item></app-bugs-item>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```